# Could I be "fired" after stating my intention to eventually switch departments?

Tags: job-search, united-states, internal-transfer

I'm in a bit of a pickle here. I work for a company in the United States. I'm in a position where there have been major team shifts in the department. New managers, new projects, stuff like that. I have the intention to leave the department in hopes of landing something new at a different department within the company.

Common wisdom says that you shouldn't state your intention to leave if you haven't already secured a new job. I get that point, but I'm in an interesting case where I don't *really* have a manger. Our team is in a flux, and we have the opportunity to *choose* our new manager so long as they are within the same organization.

My "new" manager has been kind enough to not burden me into reluctantly accepting to be under his management if I won't be happy about it.

So the questions are:

1) How do I convey to him that I'm interested in looking at different departments as well?

2) Could I be fired/laid off after stating such an intention?

I can see how this is problematic - ah, the dilemma that plagues everybody on their pursuit of happiness. I want to ultimately be happy in my new position, but I don't want to break ties or make things awkward. Since my team and myself are in a flux state at the moment, what are the cons of stating such an intent?

Comment: Can't ask about legal without giving the location

Comment: Laws in USA != Laws in Canada != Laws In Mexico, etc.

Comment: Hehe woops, meant USA :)

Comment: I don't understand your use of "leave". Do you want to continue to work at the same company but transfer to a different department (you seem to be interested in this), or do you want to quit the company entirely (the usual meaning of "leave" in this context, and suggested by your concerns about breaking ties, etc.)? Are both on the table?

Comment: I want to work at the same company, but transfer to a different department. Hence "leave" here means leave the current department in hopes to transfer elsewhere within the same company.

Comment: "at will" employment contracts generally hold in court.

Comment: legal advice is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Comment: I believe that to some extent, employment law varies by state. So "USA" is not sufficient information to answer whether something is legal or not.

Comment: I rephrased your question to remove the legal aspect, since that is off-topic for this site. Feel free to make your own changes if you want to ask the question differently.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a situation that your manager in department A wants to keep you, but the manager in department B wants you in his team as well, "the company" will not be interested in firing you, and it is likely that your manager cannot fire you when the other manager wants you (because it's probably their common manager who decides).

It wouldn't be rational of your manager to fire you for looking at jobs in different departments; it doesn't serve the interests of the company. Obviously your manager may be irrational. So I'd check out possibilities in other departments carefully if you don't trust your own manager.

You might check if your company has any policies; many companies encourage people to move from department to department to get a better understanding of the whole company and to prevent rut setting in in any department.

Answer (score 0):

In the US it's legal to fire you with no reason at all, so unless you can show that you were fired for a specifically illegal reason I don't think the law per se can help you. You could try bringing a civil suit,  but..

However, this case sounds like it might be a violation of your company's policies, so I'd suggest asking the HR department and/or your boss's boss what's going on.

I'd also check whether you were actually fired or if it was just a fit of momentary irrationality.